# C# Linq to SQL query with projection from a variant column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, projection

I have code that will run on many different systems, each with its own "name" to identify the system, and whether customers will have access to that system.

The "permissions" table is nasty legacy MySQL without foreign keys that just isn't quite ready to be normalized and rewritten for MSSQL in a better form.  (That's a longer term project and many apps have to be rewritten first).  That's why I'm using an explicit Join rather than foreign key-style queries.  So be it for now.

The essential code illustrates the problem / question:

```
using (var dc = new MySqlDataContext())
{
    var queryResult = (from c in dc.Customers
        join m in dc.MembershipGroups on c.MembershipGroup equals m.MembershipName
        where ((c.MembershipGroup != "Demo" && c.LastActivity > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-365)) ||
                (c.MembershipGroup == "Demo" && c.LastActivity > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-120) && c.Points+c.PromoPoints > 10))
        select new
        {
            c.Username,
            c.AccountPassword,
            c.FirstName,
            c.LastName,
            c.Points,
            c.PromoPoints,
            c.DeleteAccount,
            c.MembershipDate,
            c.MembershipGroup,
            c.LastActivity,
            m.<variant column>
        });
}
```

It's that last line item in the projection that is at issue.  I'm using projection because this legacy table has one column for each possible system in the farm.... over 200 columns total.  I only need the code to retrieve the column for the system ***on which it is running***.

For example, if this computer is "SYSTEM_014", there's a column in the membership_groups table called "SYSTEM_014", which contains either "Yes" or "No" as to whether this particular Membership Group has privileges to use SYSTEM_014.

I don't want to simply "select all" because that would return all 200+ columns in membership groups, for each of the several thousand customers that the query will return.  (And yes, it has to return a substantial subset of a 20K+ customer database -- that's the purpose of this program! [**]  Hence the projection.

How can I write this Linq query to "pseudo-parameterize" the actual column name from which the data will be queried?  It's easy to do normal parameterization on a "where" criteria, but I can't find anything on how to vary the SOURCE column of the query at runtime.

Any help would be appreciated.

** For the curious, as to why I need to query several thousand customers in a result set, I'm locked into reliance on a legacy app that doesn't use a database for user access control.  For the love of Pete, it actually stores privileges in the Windows REGISTRY!  So I'm re-writing an app that pulls the qualifying customer records out of our database, and parses the result set into a .REG file that can be executed to update the registry with updated permissions.  No, I can't move away from this one-of-a-kind third party app.      So, query the lot, blast out a .REG file, and then fire it off, which is FAR faster than trying to manipulate the registry line by line in C# -- which is how its done now, very, very slowly.  Moving to this format will speed things up by four orders of magnitude, and I'm using the opportunity to replace ADO code (where it was easy to concatenate a text query string on the fly and then submit it) with cleaner LINQ code.

Comment: Would you consider using something like Dynamic LINQ?  This would let you write out the field name and have it reflect back to the column in the database.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: Would dynamic Linq work with Devart's dotConnect for MySQL as well?  I'm also locked into using that, since the Oracle-based 6.8.3 connector has a bug in that it won't play nice with alternate port numbers, and too many other things are still looking for MySQL on my custom port number.